# Creating an optimized reduce on sum

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, bigdata, mpi

I have just started taking courses in HPC and am doing an assignment where we are expected to implement Reduce function equivalent to the MPI_Reduce on MPI_SUM... Easy enough right? Here is what I did:

I started with basic concept of sending data/array from all nodes to the root-node (0-th ranked process) and there I computed the sum.

As a second step I optimized it further so that each process sends data to it's mirror image which computes the sum,and this process keeps repeating until the result in finally present in the root-node (0-th process). My implementation is as follows:

```
    for(k=(size-1); k>0; k/=2)
    {
        if(rank<=k)
        {
            if(rank<=(k/2))
            {
                //receiving the buffers from different processes and computing them
                MPI_Recv(rec_buffer, count, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                for(i=0; i<count; i++)
                {
                    res[i] += rec_buffer[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MPI_Send(res, count, MPI_INT, k-rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }
    }
```

But the thing is this code performs significantly poorer compared to the MPI_Reduce function itself.

So how can I further optimize it? What can I do differently to make if better? I can't make the sum loop multi-threaded as it is required that we do it in a single thread. I can may be optimize the sum loop but not sure how and where to begin.

I apologize for a pretty basic question but I am really starting to get feet wet in the field of HPC. Thanks!

Comment: You say you send the array to the root node and compute the sum there. Why don't you build the sum in each process and only send an integer to the root?

Comment: @maraca well what I need a an array consisting of sum of multiple arrays. For instance if "a" is an array in each process what I want as result is result = a(from process 0) + a(from process 1) + a (from process 2) ... and so on... The result in the end will be an array.

Comment: Here are the various algo used by Open MPI https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/master/ompi/mca/coll/base/coll_base_reduce.c

Comment: One micro-optimization could be to instead do `if(rank <= k/2) {  MPI_Recv ... } else if (rank <= k) {  MPI_Send... }`. Might improve the branch situation ever so slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is the right one since you do the same number of communications but you have parallelized the reduce operation (sum in your case) and the communication (since you communicate between subsets). You typically do reduce operation like described in [Reduction operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_Operator).

However you may want to try asynchronous communication using MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv to improve performance and get closer to MPI_Reduce performance.

@GillesGouillardet provided one implementation, you can see that the communications in the code are done with isend and irecv (look for "MCA_PML_CALL( isend" and "MCA_PML_CALL( irecv" )